# Paging through attachments does not return expected results

Tags: querystring

I wrote some PowerShell code to page through attachments, with pagesize 500.  I got 497 results, then it stopped.  To investigate whether this was a code issue I tried accessing the URI in my web browser, skipping the first 495 records so I could see what came back.

Accessing this URI gave 4 results: `https://{tenant}.service-now.com/api/now/v1/attachment?sysparm_limit=10&sysparm_offset=495` (so doesn't quite fit with the 497 I got the first time, but still doesn't return the 10 results I'd expect if there are more than 500 attachments (as I'm pretty confident there are).

I tried going way past the first 500 to see what happened, and things get weirder.  Going to `https://{tenant}.service-now.com/api/now/v1/attachment?sysparm_limit=10&sysparm_offset=1000`, I get 6 results!

I also tried adding `&sysparm_query=ORDERBYsys_id` to the end of the URI; but it made no difference.  That said, adding `&sysparm_query=ORDERBYDESCsys_id` gave me different records, including 1 additional result for the offset=1000 scenario (i.e. I got 7 instead of 6; though with offset 495 I got 4 results both ascending and descending).

This isn't a code issue, since I can recreate the issues when accessing these URIs through the browser.

Have I misunderstood something about the API, or is this a bug on the SN side?

---

Related Documentation: https://docs.servicenow.com/integrate/inbound_rest/reference/r_AttachmentAPI-GET.html

Comment: Please could someone with access to create new tags add `[service-now]` and `[api]`?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: I resolved this by using a workaround.  I queried the TASK table, then used the `SYS_CLASS_NAME` and `SYS_ID` tables to query on `TABLE_NAME` and `TABLE_SYS_ID`, thus getting all attachments related to any tasks.  Not ideal, but should find most attachments.

Comment: [api] was burninated some time ago Ref https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3936/88163. service-now.com now redirects to servicenow.com

Comment: Thanks @Rubén.  Are you saying that this question is no inappropriate for this site?  Any suggestions on the best place for it to live?  The burninate comments mention that API issues are programming issues, but as discussed, this doesn't seem to be the case in this scenario, since I can recreate the issue via the browser.

Comment: I think that it's a question on the edge of the scope of this site. If you were trying to develop a web app, the question would be off-topic but it looks that you are trying to interact with a web application by creating a "end-user defined function" / macro. Regarding were else to ask this question, please ask on [meta.se].